# DOJO calender widget in Data Text box

Tags: dojo, calendar

I want to select a date which is 40 years ago using Dojo date text box , but using calender widget of date text box in Dojo , it is hard to navigate month to month and it will take lot of time before i reach to 40 years ago date .

Please suggest me if we can have a date text box without calendar widget popping up and thus user can type any date he wants directly into the text box.

Thanks,
Pratap.

Answer (score 0):

The popup widget can be overridden by setting the `popupClass` property.  The empty string should result in text only.  With or without a popup widget, the user should be able to modify text into the dijit/form/DateTextBox directly, and it will automatically be validated as the user types.

True, the dijit/Calendar widget is poorly optimized for selecting years far away.  Note also that you can switch from one year to the next by clicking on the previous/next year at the bottom of the calendar.